# Pandas Count Number of On/Off Events and Duration

Tags: pandas

I have a DataFrame with two columns, one containing the time of an event and the other containing whether the event is an `On` or an `Off`. I would like to count the number of times an `On` occurs followed by an `Off` as well as the total duration `On` occurs.

For example see this DataFrame:

```
Time  Event
01:00 On
01:15 Off
01:16 Off
02:00 On
02:15 Off
23:30 On
```

Would have 2 `On/Off` events with a total duration of `O:30`.

I'm sure how to approach this problem.

Comment: I'd shift, both columns, check the diffs between them, then sum if the event diffs check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a mask, which gives you the number of events. Then subtract to get the time difference.

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.Time+':00')

m = df.Event.eq('On') & df.Event.shift(-1).eq('Off')
m.sum()
#2

(df.shift(-1).loc[m, 'Time'] - df.loc[m, 'Time']).sum()
#Timedelta('0 days 00:30:00')
```